# How to calculate the sum of the differences among each pairs within 3 (or more) rows in an sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table.

```
| Score      | AssessmentId| SubmissionId |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 15         |          23 |      18      |
| 15         |          24 |      18      |
| 15         |          16 |      19      |
| 19         |          17 |      19      |
| 18         |          25 |      19      |
```

This table holds assessment scores by different users (can be inferred from `AssessmentId` for each `Submission`. What I need to do it to compute the differences among all possible scores per each submission.

For example, for submission #18: `15-15 = 0`.
For submission #19: `(19-15) + (18-15) + (19-18) = 8`

As one option I tried `LAG` function:

```
PARTITION BY SubmissionId
 ORDER BY AssessmentId
 ) previous_month FROM (
SELECT SUM(CurrentScore) as Score, AssessmentId, SubmissionId
FROM AssessmentItems INNER JOIN dbo.Assessments ON dbo.AssessmentItems.AssessmentId = dbo.Assessments.Id      
WHERE IsActive = 1
GROUP BY AssessmentId, SubmissionId) as TBL
```

which produced:

```
| Score      | AssessmentId| SubmissionId |   PrevScore  |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 15         |          23 |      18      |   NULL       |
| 15         |          24 |      18      |   15         |
| 15         |          16 |      19      |   NULL       |
| 19         |          17 |      19      |   15         |
| 18         |          25 |      19      |   19         |
```

From this table, I can get differences between `Score` and `PrevScore` but this still does not cover all the possibilities. For example for submission #19, `19-18` will not be computed.

I wonder if someone help move forward from here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a self-join:

```
WITH a AS (
      SELECT SUM(CurrentScore) as Score, AssessmentId, SubmissionId
      FROM AssessmentItems ai INNER JOIN
           dbo.Assessments a
           ON ai.AssessmentId = a.Id      
      WHERE IsActive = 1
      GROUP BY AssessmentId, SubmissionId
     )
SELECT a1.SubmissionId, a1.Score, a2.Score,
       (a2.Score - a1.Score) as diff
FROM a a1 JOIN
     a a2
     ON a1.SubmissionId = a2.SubmissionId AND
        a1.Score < a2.Score;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
declare @tbl table ( Score int, AssessmentId int, SubmissionId int);
insert into @tbl values
( 15 , 23 , 18 ),
( 15 , 24 , 18 ),
( 15 , 16 , 19 ),
( 19 , 17 , 19 ),
( 18 , 25 , 19 );

select SubmissionId, sum(Score * recordsCount - scoreSum)
from (
    select *,
           sum(score) over (partition by SubmissionId order by Score rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) scoreSum,
           sum(1) over (partition by SubmissionId order by Score rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) recordsCount
    from @tbl
) a where scoreSum is not null
group by SubmissionId
```

Explanation:

having this formula `(19-15) + (18-15) + (19-18)` we can rewrite it as:

```
19 * 2 + 18 * 1 - (15 + 18) - 15
```

First part `19 * 2 + 18 * 1` is `Score` multiplied by preceding records count.

Second part is cumulative sum over `Score` of preceding recrods:

- (15 + 18) for 19
- 15 for 18